# Where should this code parts go?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, architecture, frameworks

I have a simple website, where users can upload pictures, and give them titles.

Upload form should work without JavaScript and with JavaScript (as a form on layer with XHRs).

I have a:

- Form_Upload
- Model_Post (with it's Gateway/Mapper)
- UploadController
- SuperDuper - class/resource which handles file uploads, generates thumbnails, stores images etc.

Things I think must be done in UploadController::uploadAction are:

1. Create new form
2. Check if it's POST request or GET request
3. Check if it's XHR request or regular request
4. Vaidate form
5. Download/receive file from form
6. Valide file's MIME type
7. Convert file using SuperDuper, and return attachment ID
8. If everything is fine save Post data with attachment ID to database
9. Return reponse in appropriate context
10. Return error message/form errors in appropriate context

And it seems like a lot of things to be done in one Action.

And there are lot's of "ifs" because this action should handle different contexts: GET, XHR POST, POST.

Is there any good Zend way to handle such cases (and I believe it's pretty much a popular one). Should I make additional private functions in Controller to handle parts of the request, or requestes depending on context?

My action is now 140 lines long, and seems wrong.

Comment: not sure why you would even allow GET for an upload.

Comment: Good point, to clarify: this action for GET request would return just an upload form, and not handle the upload itself.foo.bar/upload handles upload only with POST.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should give some parts of code to your form class which use Zend_Form. In this class should be points 1,4,5,6. And 10 you should better display in flashmassanger. The rest of yur points must be on action, so you must invoke form in action too.

Comment: Thanks, 1. Create form = $form = new Application_Form_Post(); - so all the code is in Forms/Post.php file of course.

Comment: 10. I'm using flashmessage only when I'm redirecting to a different action, after upload was successful, which isn't the case here.

Comment: And why do you think 5 and 6 should be in Forms/Post.php file? And where in Forms/Post.php exactly?

Comment: When you add file field to your form. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html